# Get parent in the same jar of a classpath resource

Tags: java, classloader, embedded-jetty

I have in the resources of my Maven project an index.html file in the res/html folder.
I am running **Jetty as an embedded webserver**. I want to tell him that the base resource for static content is the res/ folder.

So, I tried:

```
ResourceHandler rh = new ResourceHandler();
rh.setResourceBase(getClass().getResource("/res").toURI().toString());
```

It worked until I included another jar on my classpath which also have a res/ folder.
Jetty started to look for static content in `thisotherjar.jar!res/`

I would like to avoid having to give literally the path of the jar that contains my res folder. I am looking for something more generic. I tried to start with the **classpath** of the file `index.html` and then go up the the res folder using `URI.resolve("..")` but the same problem happens.

Any ideas to solve this nicely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a name that is less prone to collisions, exactly like for the Java packages. You do not name a package `res` because if everyone did that there would be conflicts every time we incorporate two libs.

Instead of the `res` directory give it a name that is specific to you such as `com/mycompany/myproject/res`.

Comment: OK thanks. I will do it like that. It makes very long paths but indeed it seems the way to go.